# Execute code after last method in method chain is executed

Tags: java, aspectj, freefair-aspectj

Can I create an aspect that will inject some code in the end of builder method chain in builder-like pattern?

End-goal is to execute `build` method automatically inside aspect(and not necessarily `build` method, but any other code) without specifying it in code directly.

Here is minimal example:
builder interface:

```java
public interface Builder {
  Builder withArg1(Arg1 arg1);
  Builder withArg2(Arg2 arg2);
  ...
  Builder withArgN(ArgN argN);
  void build();
}
```

method chain example:

```java
createBuilder().withArg2(arg2).withArg10(arg10)
```

expected aspect must be executed after `.withArg10(arg10)` method.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve that way?

Comment: @kriegaex more fluent and easy to use extensions to kotlin dsl. For cases where dsl subparts perform their actions immediately.

Comment: For example, `job { execute("hello").onError { println("error") } }` will be possible. For now I use syntax like `execute { binary("hello") onError{...}}`, which add an extra block.

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: @kriegaex updated question a little bit, thanks.

Comment: No problem, then I wish good luck to you, to also get a little bit of an answer. 

Comment: @kriegaex I have a strong feeling that aspectj can't do it :)

Answer (score 1):

What you want, does not make much sense. Look at your example:

```java
createBuilder().withArg2(arg2).withArg10(arg10)
```

That is just source code. After being compiled, it looks the same as

```java
Builder builder = createBuilder();
builder = builder.withArg2(arg2);
builder = builder.withArg10(arg10);
```

AspectJ is a tool for instrumenting byte code. Therefore, it does not see this as a single line of source code with syntactic sugar for a fluent API, but just as a bunch of method calls.

Now, when we extend the sample code a bit to look like this:

```java
Builder builder = createBuilder();
builder = builder.withArg2(arg2);
builder = builder.withArg10(arg10);
// Do something else
builder = builder.withArg3(arg3);
builder = builder.withArg7(arg7);
// Do something else
builder = builder.withArg5(arg5);
```

How is any aspect or even source code transformer expected to know when you are done, calling (fluent API) methods on your builder and are ready for the final call `builder.build()`? Even assuming, that you would use a hypothetical tool analysing and transforming source code, this would be a difficult task, because the user always has a choice to call builder methods separately or in one long chain or mix both approaches like this:

```java
Builder builder = createBuilder().withArg2(arg2).withArg10(arg10);
// Do something else
builder = builder.withArg3(arg3).withArg7(arg7).withArg5(arg5);
```

What you want is not just a technological challenge, but it simply does not make a ton of sense. Why would you take away the decision from the user to decide when she is done calling builder methods and ready to call `build()`? How is an aspect even supposed to know? And why hide the `build()` call in your source code, documenting the user's intent? As much as I love AOP, this use case here is not a cross-cutting concern. From a tool or AOP paradigm perspective, it is  rather the equivalent to trying to use a hammer to dig a hole.

Comment: Yep, now I understand that is not AOP problem(and not a problem at all, just was trying to do something... don't know non-filthy English word to describe it :) ) . For source code transform tool that is not a big deal, really(with some limitations). - don't allow that builder variable leak out of current scope. Probably bytecode manipulation can follow that rules as well, but bytecode will not keep all blocks that source code can have...